# Does an ExtJS application share a session with the rest of an HTML page

Tags: ajax, node.js, extjs, web

I've just recently started working with ExtJS and Node.js, and I'm not quite sure how to handle authentication with this new stack.  I'm coming from a Grails + Spring Security Core background, where a web page is built with GSPs and the client maintains a session when making requests of the server.  Would an ExtJS application behave the same way when loading a JsonStore, or would I have to fall back to basic or digest authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS is just a javascript based UI framework. It does not interfere with session management capabilities of hosting webpage that could be a jsp, asp or simple html file. ExtJS is just helping you in designing a rich front-end but underlying protocol is still http. 
It is your server side layer that has to handle authentication.